# How to find the distinct values in a nested type field in elasticsearch? Can anyone provide one example?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for one example on how to extract distinct values of a nested type property in elastic search. Could anyone provide an example?

I have a below query where I am trying to retrieve distinct values of "batchId" from nested type "admin" as follows:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "groupBatches" : {
            "nested": {
                "path": "admin"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "batches" : {
                    "terms" : {"field" : "admin.ids.batchId"} 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If what I am trying is wrong, Please provide some example for better understanding.

Comment: What is wrong with the query as it is now? What does your mapping look like?

Comment: This elastic search facilities is provided by the REST end point. All we need to do is query and get the results.
Do you think there is something wrong with the mapping? All I know is "admin" is a nested type.
If the query looks right, what should I make sure for the mapping to look like for the above query to provide correct results?

Comment: The mapping has to be setup for the admin field as nested data type else it will be treated as array type by default. I am not sure what to make of your comment, ES is a RESTFul engine that is basic stuff

Comment: @ookboy24 "admin" is  nested for sure. In my previous comment, if you see I mentioned "admin" mapping is nested.
Below is the mapping for "admin"..


{
                           "admin_as_nested": {
                               "path_match": "admin",
                               "mapping": {
                                   "type": "nested"
                               }
                           }
                       }

Comment: If you think there is nothing wrong in the query I posted, not sure what am I missing here.. I am not seeing any aggregation result when I hit the query. All it does is retrieve all the records as is. 

I do not see any aggregation ("groupBatches") specific results.

Comment: @Deepak Could you share the mapping? The above query works correctly, you do get the list of distinct `batchIds` in the aggregation section of the result. I've created a sample index with `admin` as nested type and ran the query. It's the correct one. If you can share the mapping details, I can further look into it.

Comment: Sure @Kamal, thank you for the follow-up. I will ask for the mappings. Could you also share the mapping for the sample data you tried on?